# Questionw about Random Mapping Representation

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am reading *Markov chain and Mixing time* and I do not understand the following two things:

> A random mapping representation of a transition matrix P on a state $\Omega$ is a function $f:\Omega\times\Lambda \rightarrow \Omega$ along with a $\Lambda$-valued random variable $Z$, satisfying 
>   $$\textbf{P}\{f(x,Z)=y \}=P(x,y)$$
>   *The reader should chech that if $Z_1,Z_2,\dots$ is a sequence of independent random variables, each having the same distribution as $Z$, and $X_0$ has distribution $\mu$, then the sequence $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$ defined by* 
>   $$X_n=f(X_{n-1}, Z_n)$$
>   is a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ and initial distribution $\mu$.

Here I missing something because I could not prove what the author asks. I ask for a calculation and to know where should the independence of the random variables $Z_1,Z_2,\cdots$ is used.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: If $n=1$

$$\textbf{P}(X_1=y|X_0=x)=\textbf{P}(f(X_0,Z_1)=y|X_0=x)=\textbf{P}(f(x_0,Z)=y)=P(x,y)$$

and that

$$\textbf{P}(X_2=y|X_1=x_1,X_0=x)=\textbf{P}(f(X_1,Z_2)=y|X_1=x,X_0=x_0)\overset{?}{=}\textbf{P}(f(x,Z_2)=y|X_0=x_0)\overset{?}{=}P(x,y)$$

It the next I do the same:
$$\textbf{P}(X_{t+1}=y|X_{t}=x,X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\dots X_0=x_0)=\textbf{P}(f(X_t,Z_t)=y|X_{t}=x,X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\dots X_0=x_0)=\textbf{P}(f(x,Z_t)=y|X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\dots X_0=x_0)\overset{?}{=}\textbf{P}(X_{t+1}=y|X_{t}=x)\overset{?}{=}P(x,y)$$

But I don't know if this is right and if so why and where the independency is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need independence because $X_n$ depends on $Z_n$, and unless $Z_n$ is independent of, say, $Z_{n-2}$ then there's no guarantee that the distribution of $X_n$ conditional on $X_{n-1}$ is independent of $X_{n-2}$.

As for the proof it should literally just consist of unpacking the definition.  Do you know the precise definition of a Markov chain?

**UPDATE**

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}&(X_n = c_n \; | \; X_{n-1} = c_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = c_0) \\[3mm]
&= \mathbb{P}(f(x_{n-1}, Z_n) = c_n \; | \; f(x_{n-2}, Z_{n-1}) = c_{n-1}, \ldots, f(x_0, Z_{1}) = c_1, X_0 = c_0) \\[3mm]
&= \mathbb{P}(f(x_{n-1}, Z_n) = c_n) = P(x_{n-1},c_{n-1})
\end{align*}

where the next-to-last step comes from the independence of $Z_n$ from the other $Z_i$.  (In fact we also need to require that each $Z_i$ is independent of $X_0$, which the question didn't explicitly mention.)

Comment: I do. I must prove that $\textbf{P}(X_{t+1}=y|X_{t}=x,X_{t-1}=x_{t-1}\dots X_0=x_0)=\textbf{P}(X_{t+1}=y|X_{t}=x)=P(x,y)$.

Comment: But I am not sure what kind of calculations I can do. Can I post my try and you can tell what is wrong?

Comment: @YTS: Yes.  Edit it into your original question.

Comment: Done with the edit.

Comment: @YTS: See update.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on how the last step follows? Why does the conditional probability go away? @DanielMcLaury