# How to show that a random mapping representation of a sequence is a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This post: [Questionw about Random Mapping Representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082409/questionw-about-random-mapping-representation) did not make it clear for me why the defined sequence is a Markov chain? We need to show that $P(X_n = c_n | X_{n - 1} = c_{n - 1},...,X_0 = c_0) = P(X_n = c_n | X_{n - 1} = c_{n - 1})$. From the definition of the sequence it follows that $P(f(X_{n-1}, Z_n) = c_n | f(X_{n-2},Z_{n-1}) = c_{n-1},...,X_0 = c_0) = P(f(X_{n-1},Z_n) = c_n) = P(X_n, c_n)$

by the i.i.d. of all $Z_i$. I do not see how this concludes the proof.